# How are Google Analytics retention numbers over 100%?

Tags: flutter, google-analytics, analytics, firebase-analytics

We have a Flutter App using Firebase Analytics. We integrated the analytics about 4 months ago. 3 weeks ago we realized that the number of users shown by the analytics dashboard is much higher than what we actually have (about 10 times). It was because we were not setting a USER ID explicitly, so every install and reinstall of the app was getting counted as a user. We corrected it by calling **setUserId** from the app with a unique identifier for each user.

Now when we are looking at the Firebase Analytics dashboard we are filtering of “**Signed with User ID**” dimension and the number of users shown seems correct. But with this filter the retention numbers are weird. The retention numbers are shown to be 100% for one day on the chart. And on the weekly retention plot, it is even beyond 100% for the second week.
We are finding it difficult to interpret these kinds of retention numbers. Is there something missing from our side or are we not looking at them correctly?

[image]
[image]

Also, the week-on-week retention is shown to be 167%. How can we get accurate retention numbers?

[image]

Appreciate any input from you on how can we get the correct retention numbers.